# Is there support to Capture Video with Sound in phonegap (cordova)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is there support to Capture Video with Sound in phonegap (cordova)?
I checked on my iPad a phonegap 3.1 app whit Video Capture and no sound recording with the video

appreciate help 
Thanks

```
function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
        var ft = new FileTransfer(),
            path = mediaFile.fullPath,
            name = mediaFile.name;

        ft.upload(path,
            "http://www/api/up_video",
            function(result) {
                cordova.logger.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                cordova.logger.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
            },
            function(error) {
                cordova.logger.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
            },
            { fileName: name });
}


// capture callback
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        name = mediaFiles[i].name;
        // do something interesting with the file
        alert(name);
        //alert(mediaFiles[i].size);
        //alert(mediaFiles[i].type);
        uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
    }
};

// capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error'); 
    cordova.logger.log( error); 
};

  navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {duration:6});
```

Comment: did you find a way to capture video without leaving your phonegap app? we're looking to do something similar.

Comment: phonegap capture plugin

Comment: we need the video to get captured while the app is still being used in the foreground. also, did you find a solution to capturing both video & audio at the same time? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Both video and sound can be captured using Phonegap's "Capture" API. See documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#Capture).

Edit based on comments:

You are never telling the device to capture audio. The capture of Video and Audio are different operations. You need to also call the `navigator.device.capture.captureAudio` function. See [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#CaptureAudioOptions).

Comment: I will try to explain better. I want video with sound. Right now I can shoot video with no sound in the video, only silent films...

Comment: Need to show some code then. When you start video recording, you also need to start audio recording. Just starting video will not auto start audio.

Comment: Your answer does not make sense and does not work...  I want video with sound in the video file :) ...

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you. The captureVideo api captures video. The captureAudio API captures audio. You need to instantiate both in order to get both. Yes, you will end up with two separate files. Yes, you will need to join those files together on your server side script. I am sure this will be addressed in a later feature but right now, you have what you have and nothing more.